# Docker stack "--force-recreate" in swarm mode using compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to do a force recreation of containers using compose file in docker swarm mode ? (I am aware of using HEALTHCHECK in Dockerfile)

Currently i have to remove the stack first & then deploy it again -

`$ docker stack deploy -c stg-sm-deploy-compose.yml --with-registry-auth MY-APP`

`$ docker stack rm MY-APP`

`$ docker stack deploy -c stg-sm-deploy-compose.yml --with-registry-auth MY-APP`

Is there any possibility that above 3 commands can be replaced by -

`$ docker stack deploy -c stg-sm-deploy-compose.yml --with-registry-auth MY-APP --force-recreate`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For any service created inside that stack that didn't change, you can use:

```
docker service update --force $service
```

which will force a rolling update of that service.

To recreate everything from a stack, enter your stack name as `$stack` in:

```
docker stack services -q $stack \
  | while read service; do
    docker service update --force $service
  done
```

Comment: Great direction/help @BMitch . Just a small correction , docker does't support "-f" flag anymore we have to use "--force" . Working command in my case is `docker service update --force MY-APP_nginx` .

Comment: Thanks for the correction. That's what I get for answering from memory, they may never have had a `-f` for force since that's also short flag for format and filter in other commands.

Comment: If I changed the content of my compose file, does updating a service with `docker service update --force $service` take the new configuration for this service into account?

Comment: @papillon no, you haven't provided a compose file in this command, it's not even a stack command. You're just replacing containers in a deployed service.

Answer (score 4):

We can force re-create a particular service defined in the compose file in swarm mode -

1. Get service name -

   `$ docker service ls`
2. Force-update/recreate it -

   `$ docker service update --force MY-APP_nginx`

   Where "nginx" is the service name defined in compose file & MY-APP is the name of the stack .

Answer (score 1):

An extension of @BMitch's answer, with a little less shell.

```sh
$ docker stack services -q $stack \
  | xargs -rt -n1 -- docker service update --force
...
```